# Standard exact sequence for a complete intersection

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose $P$ is a variety over $\mathbb{C}$ (in my case $P$ might have slight singularities), and $V=D_1\cap\dotsb\cap D_r$ is a complete intersection. Then, it is claimed exists the so called "Standard exact sequence for a complete intersection":

$$0 \to \mathscr O_{V}(-D_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathscr O_{V}(-D_r) \to \Omega_{P}^{1}|_V \to \Omega_{V}^1 \to 0$$

Does anyone know how to show the above exact sequence? Or point out some reference having discussiong about such things? Moreover, what are the corresponding sequence for the $p$-forms (i.e. the sequence tells something about $\Omega_{P}^{p}|_V $ and $\Omega_{V}^p $ )?

Comment: This is a consequence of the adjunction exact sequence. Each term corresponds to a generator of the ideal.

Comment: Could do say something more about your answer? What do you mean by adjunction exact sequence?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunction_formula_(algebraic_geometry)

Comment: Look at Hartshorne 2.8...

Comment: Do you find this question satisfyingly answered with the references? If not, I could post a more detailed answer. If so, this question should be closed.

Comment: @Will Sawin I find the comments for my first question is helpful, however, nothing has been said about the second one, i.e. the exact sequence about p-form. I will be very appreciate if you can say something in details.

Comment: I am also curious about this question. If $P$ is smooth, then this is a consequence of the adjunction formula. What if $P$ has, say, cyclic quotient singularities and $X$ is a smooth complete intersection in $P$?

Comment: @Brian Fitzpatrick: Except for the injectivity of the first nontrivial arrow, the sequence is exact regardless of the singularities of $P$, see Hartshorne, II, Prop. 8.12. It is exact on a dense open subset of $V$, hence everywhere because the left hand term is torsion free.

Comment: @abx Are there conditions on the singularities of $P$ that ensure the exactness of the first nontrivial arrow if $V$ is smooth?

Comment: If $V$ is smooth and is a complete intersection in $P$, then $P$ is smooth along $V$.